# How to have more then 30sec response timeout in heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, server, hosting

Guys Heroku is terminating the req if the response takes more then 30sec to return, so is there any way I can wait for as long as the response would come back?

Well the user is uploading his file and I need to do something with the file in my server and after updates are done I will give a download link to the user. But mostly it takes more then 30 sec for the server to process the file so that the user need to wait for response

Comment: Why is a request taking more than 30 seconds? Maybe you should restructure it anyway, see e.g. https://farazdagi.com/posts/2014-10-16-rest-long-running-jobs/.

Comment: Well the user is uploading his file and I need to do something with the file in my server and after updates are done I will give a download link to the user. But mostly it takes more then 30 sec for the server to process the file so that the user need to wait for response

Answer (score 1):

From the official Heroku Helpcenter : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout

> The timeout value is not configurable. If your server requires longer than 30 seconds to complete a given request, we recommend moving that work to a background task or worker to periodically ping your server to see if the processing request has been finished. This pattern frees your web processes up to do more work, and decreases overall application response times.

The short answer is : No, you can't change this configuration. I suggest you investigate why your application needs more than 30 seconds to process that request. If it takes longer than 10 seconds your really should consider the steps suggested in the Heroku Help Center

**Your Problem**

You mention you need this for file processing. I understand that file processing could easily take longer than 30 seconds. Normally what I would do is to just create some sort of task reference and keep it in a database along with a status ("processing", "finished", "failed") - also store the original file and then just end the request of the user. This shouldn't take long. Then process the task ... with another endpoint or websocket connection the user could check if the task has been fullfilled.

## Use a Task Queue

The following is just a basic interpretation of a solution - it's not meant for copy & pasting as it depends on so many things.

#### Routes (Endpoints)

Basically you need to have 3 routes in your backend. One for uploading the file, one for downloading the processed file and one for checking the status of the task.

##### 1. Upload

```js
app.post('/files', /* some middleware e.g. multer */, async (req, res) => {
  
  // This is your upload controller
  // I assume at this point the file has been uploaded and
  // req.file contains a reference to the uploaded file. 

  // create new process task and add to queue
  const task = await createNewTask(req.file); 
  queue.push(task);

  // now a task has been created, but the user
  // doesn't need to wait for it to finish
  // so let's end the request here. 
  return req.status(200).json(task); 

});
```

##### 2. Check Status

```js
app.get('/task/:id', async (req, res) => {
 
  // From uploading a file in the first step, you'll
  // get back a task id. Use the task id to check on 
  // the status. 

  const task = await getTask(req.params.id);
  if (!task) {
    return res.status(404).end();
  } else {
    return res.status(200).json(task);
  }

});
```

The task can include informations like status, progress percentage, original filename, new filename or even a download link to the processed file once it's finished. Status could be something like `pending`, `processing`, `finished` or `failed`.

##### 3. Download

```js
app.get('/file/:filename', (req, res) => {
  return req.status(200)
            .sendFile('./path/to/file/' + req.params.filename);
});
```

#### Notes

- It might be a good idea to rename the incoming files with a random id like a uuid. So it's easier to work with them in the automation process. Also the random id could be used for the task id at the same time.
- It's up to you how big you want to go with this. For the task queue there are many different libraries to help you out with it. It could be an in-memory queue or one that's backed with a database.

Comment: Can you please give some reference about with another endpoint, actually I'm new so Idk about that. I would be pleased by your help

Comment: I ll try to get to it later if no one beats me too it :)

Comment: Well I don't think anyone has a solution haha :)

Comment: @user16606396 Let me know if this helped you